# Use a parameter as a tag in a mixin

Tags: sass

How can I do that :

```
@mixin addMargin($el) {
    $el {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    $el:hover {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

using sass ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried `@mixin addMargin { margin-left: 5px; &:hover{margin-left:10px;}}`?

Comment: Thanks Yogu, your solution is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a mixin, you can not only add properties directly to an element, but you can also add more rules:

```
@mixin addMargin {
  margin-left: 5px;

  &:hover {
    margin-left:10px;
  }
}
```

Note that you have to prefix the `:hover` with `&` so that we get this rule:

```
#something-with-the-mixin-applied:hover
```

instead of

```
#something-with-the-mixin-applied :hover
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
@mixin addMargin($el) {
  #{$el} {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  #{$el}:hover {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

@include addMargin(h1);
```

But Yogu is right, you don't need it here. You may omit selectors, leaving only directives in your mixin, and apply the mixin inside a selector:

```
@mixin addMargin {
  margin-left: 5px;

  &:hover {
    margin-left:10px;
  }
}

h1 {
  @include addMargin;
}
```